# Button Text not updating within eventListener

Tags: javascript

Button text is not updating when the event is triggered. This is a submit event but I've also tried a click event. I've also tested the code outside of the event listener and it works correctly. So the problem seems to be within the event listener.
Here is the code:

```
let addToCartForms = document.querySelectorAll(".bundle-builder--add-to-bundle-form");
    addToCartForms.forEach((el)=>{
        let btn = el.querySelector('.add-to-cart');
        let btnText = btn.innerText;
        
        el.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
            btn.innerText = "added"
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `click` and `submit` work. Maybe the form is submitted so you can't see the effect?

```js
let addToCartForms = document.querySelectorAll(".bundle-builder--add-to-bundle-form");
addToCartForms.forEach((el) => {
  let btn = el.querySelector('.add-to-cart');
  let btnText = btn.innerText;

  el.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    btn.innerText = "added"
  });
})
```

```html
<form class="bundle-builder--add-to-bundle-form">

  <button class="add-to-cart">click</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What I'm seeing is that the textText is changing by looking at the element in the console. However, the text is not updating on that button. Any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: See other answer that allows for timeout before the submit. Maybe even a timeout of 1ms could do the trick.

Comment: I tried that as well but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: I can only suggest you try elimination to find the reason because it should work. You can share relevant HTML and CSS if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this jQuery solution could work.

```js
$('body').on('submit', '.bundle-builder--add-to-bundle-form .add-to-cart', function(e){ 
  (e).preventDefault();
  (this).text('added');
   setTimeout(function() {
  (this).submit()},500)
})
```